# What mathematical principal allows this rearrangement during simplifying

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, special-relativity

\begin{align}
t^2 &= (t^I)^2-\frac{v^2}{c^2}(t^I)^2 \\
t^2 &= (t^I)^2\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)
\end{align}

I've been researching Einstein's Special Relativity Theory and would love to know the ins and outs of the equations.  I haven't taken a algebra course in almost two decades and simplifying the equations was making sense until this came up (image related.)  What mathematical principal is this called when rearranging the right side of the equation?  It doesn't make sense at all.  I don't need a direct explanation as much as what rule it is so I can further research it myself.   Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's just distribution. $a(b+c)=ab+ac$.

Comment: Oh wow.  That is so embarrassing.  It had an odd look but I can see it now that you told me.  Thanks.

Comment: It's worth stating that while this is an application of the distributive property of multiplication, the act of using it this was is referred to as *factoring*, as a factor of $(t^I)^2$ is being removed from the various monomials in the expression.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post to make it neater and further explaining.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) For some basic information about writing math
at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editikng how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). 
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).

Comment: @GNUSupporter edit the title. There is no picture here.

Comment: It is also commutativity

Comment: @Improve I fail to see how commutativity was used. I see nothing other than left distributivity at work here.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Well, $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ vs $a(b+c) = ab + ca$